# Benchmark Go code and goroutines

Tags: go, benchmarking, goroutine

I would like to benchmark a function: `test()`, with different numbers of threads working on it.

### Without goroutines:

```
var t1 = time.Now()
test()
var elapsed1 = time.Since(t1)
```

> 1 ns / operation

### With goroutines:

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
var t1 = time.Now()
go test()
var elapsed1 = time.Since(t1)
```

> 1.10^-6 ns / operation

### My test function:

```
func test() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000000000; i++ {
        float_result = f1 + f2
        float_result = f1 - f2
        float_result = f1 * f2
        float_result = f1 / f2
        float_result = f1 + f2
        float_result = f1 - f2
        float_result = f1 * f2
        float_result = f1 / f2
        float_result = f1 + f2
        float_result = f1 - f2
        float_result = f1 * f2
        float_result = f1 / f2
        float_result = f1 + f2
        float_result = f1 - f2
        float_result = f1 * f2
        float_result = f1 / f2
        float_result = f1 + f2
        float_result = f1 - f2
        float_result = f1 * f2
        float_result = f1 / f2
    }
}
```

- Is the test() function well benchmarked when I use goroutines in this case?
- How is it possible to reach 0.001ns / operation? It looks to be way too fast. (2.5GHz Intel Core i7)
- Is the use of goroutines with `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n)` equivalent to use n threads ?

Comment: Any decent compiler for any language is going to throw out almost all the code in your loop since your float_result value is never used. You need to write it to output or a file.

Comment: And even if you did use float_result at the end, only the final line would run because all the others are being overwritten.

Comment: I would like to do many operations, how can I do it without using the same variable many times ? If I do var = f1 + f2 + f3 + f4, it will write the  f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 value directly after compiling, no ?

Answer (score 8):

You are not measuring the time that `test()` runs, but the time it takes to call/create a new goroutine with `go test()`.

You need to wait for your goroutine(s) to finish, for example by using a [sync.Waitgroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

```
// somewhere in your main package
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func test() {
   // first lines in test() should be
   wg.Add(1)
   defer wg.Done()
   ...
}


// benchmark
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
var t1 = time.Now()
go test()
wg.Wait()
var elapsed1 = time.Since(t1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are tring to benchmark something so small that measurement error dominates. Your benchmark iterations should be adjusted until the benchmark function lasts long enough to be timed reliably.Your benchmark should run for about one second to be meaningful.

Comment: Even if I have 10 billion loops in the `test()` function, I have the same result. Moreover, with `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)`, the difference should not be that big than without goroutine, isn't it ?

Comment: @Nico401: Show us your test function: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I did it, I'm sure you will recognize it :)

Comment: @Nico401: "unlike with a regular call, program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete." [Go statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements). So you gave the goroutine to the scheduler, got the time, and ended the program. It didn't take long!